# How to create an advanced counter in C?

Tags: c, timer, counter

I have an infinite for loop that contains a function to continuously receive readings from a LDR. The code is something like this :

```
.
light_1=sample(1);
.
.
for(::){
 light_2=sample(2);
 if((light_2 > (light_1))
 alarm=1;
 delay(1); // wait for 1 second
.
.
.
}etc
```

light_2 is the light being sampled now, and compared to the first sampled light, light_1.

What I want to do is create a counter that if light_2 is greater than light_1 3 times, break the loop. But no just that, a light will flash 3 times at a 1 second interval. I want the loop to break ONLY if the light flashed 3 times <strike>under 4 seconds.</strike>

If this doesnt make sense please tell me so I can explain it better.

---

---

EDIT 3

I want it to continue doing the normal sampling time and only break the loop if 3 instances of readings are obtained. However I still feel I should use a timer ?? Please help.

EXTRA INFO : I replied to one of the answerers here and maybe others can benefit from this extra explanation :

There are 2 stages :

1. Stage 1 : Detect light one instance at a time. (got the code to work for this one)
2. Stage 2 : Detect light (3 consecutive flashes) to do another function.

I should avoid using so many delays to get Stage 2 to work, because that will affect the reading accuracing and speed in Stage 1.

Please let me know if you need more explanation !

Comment: Just a tip: make sure that the comparison takes the reader noise into consideration. Any changes in ambient light conditions could cause a false detection.

Comment: Yes im trying to solve that as well :)

Comment: you want to detect 3 distincts flashes emitted with exactly 1 second between 2 flashes? or 3 flashes but the periodicity can be different of 1 second ? if so check my answer... i wrote 2 codes, one for each case...

Comment: Sorry but i had to downvote. After 3 edits and several answers this is still really messy and unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Use some sort of struct to group various parameters together. This is usually called "state".

```
struct state {
     int light_2_greater_than_1;
     int other_things;
};
```

Then update that object, and check its members.

Comment: Could you please provide more detail to what you mean ?

Comment: Instead of using one integer as "counter", you asked for a more "complex" counter mechanism. So, use a struct that holds the state, instead of an integer.

Answer (score 3):

this is very simple example illustrating the use of SIGALRM to keep time independent of your sample() function, this is in case sample() is taking some time to finish, you can always do now = time(NULL) just before the sleep/delay

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

time_t now;
void alarm_handler(int sig);
struct flash {
    time_t first_stamp;
    int count;
};
int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
    now = time(NULL);
    struct flash f = {0,0};
    int light = 0;
    alarm(1); 
    for (;;) {
//      light = sample.. 
        if (light) {
            if (f.count) {
                if (f.count > 3 && (now - f.first_stamp) > 4) {
//                  do_whatever_function or break;
                    f.count = 0;
                    f.first_stamp = 0;
                } else {
                    f.count++;
                }
            } else {
                f.first_stamp = now;
                f.count = 1;
            }
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
void alarm_handler(int sig) {
    now = time(NULL);
    alarm(1);
}
```

edit:
actually now that i read it time() is not signal safe, gimme a sec to modify the code

second edit:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04 
actually it is signal safe :)

> > The following table defines a set of functions that shall be either reentrant or non-interruptible by signals and shall be async-signal-safe. Therefore applications may invoke them, without restriction, from signal-catching functions:
> >     ... time()

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply, I thought of ignoring the 4 second interval condition because it adds lots of complexity to the code. But this looks like it could work, will give it a try !

Answer (score 1):

A counter can be as simple as:

```
int count = 0;

...

if (condition)
{
    count++;
}
```

Now, to incorporate that into your loop, you might do something like:

```
int count = 0;

while (count < THRESHOLD)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, but thats a simple counter. How can I say if that condition happens in less than 4 seconds, then break ?

Comment: @Fendi, always keep the timestamps of the three last flashes (that is, with each new one, keep the new one and throw that 4th one out) and make your `while` condition like this: `while (count < THRESHOLD || now - time_of_third_last_flash > 4seconds)`

Answer (score 1):

you want to detect 3 distincts flashes emitted with exactly 1 second between 2 flashes ?
so 3 flashes in 2 seconds (not 4)... ?
(flash1 is the start, flash2 after 1 second, flash2 after 2 seconds. so 3 flashes in 2 seconds).

here is a simple code with no timer and no array that do this detection :

```
light_1=sample(1);
for(::){
    // the while loop waits for the first flash, ie : wait for sample(2) > light_1
    while(sample(2) <= (light_1))
    { 
        // if you know that a flash lasts n ms, you can add "sleep(n);" in this loop,  so you will use less cpu.
    }
    // now the first flash is emitted, we will wait for 1 second before looking for the second flash
    delay(1);
    if(sample(3) <= light_1)
        continue;
    // if after 1 second, there is no flash, ther will not be 3 flashes in 2 seconds.
    // so we restart from the first flash (the "continue;" instruction do that)   
    delay(1); // the second flash was catched, then we wait for 1 second before looking for the third flash.
    if(sample(4) <= light_1)
        continue;
    //so if sample(4 > light_1), we have 3 flashes, each 2 are separated by 1 second then you can do the function you want.
    do function...
    // once finish the function, we loop back to the beginning to start looking for the first flash again.
}
```

you have to be sure that light_1 = sample(1) was not taken when a flash was emitted.
i think of two ways to do that :

1 - if you know the lenght of the flash (eg : 20 ms), take 3 or 4 values separated with the lenght of the flash to get of good value of light_1 :

```
int i; 
light_1 = sample(1); 
for(i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
{
    light_1 = sample(1) < light_1 ? sample(1) : light_1; 
    sleep(20); // 20 = 20 ms. you can replace 20 by lenght_of_flash
}
```

2 - by a calibration. then you can use a value obtained with no light flash to init light_1;

---

if you want to get 3 flashes whithin 4 seconds without knowing the periodicity, i think it is necessary to use a timer :

here is <s>pseudo</s> code :

```
light_1 = sample();
int nb_flashes = 0;
bool fail = false;
clock_t start;  to contain the time
for(::)
{
    fail = false;
    nb_flashes = 0;
    start = clock();  //get the time to count 4 seconds.
    while(nb_flashes <3)
    {
       while(sample() <= (light_1))
      { 
        sleep(1);
      }
      nb_flashes ++; 
      if( (clock() - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC >=4)
      {
        fail = true;  //more than 4 seconds where elapsed... so we restart from the beginning of the for loop.
        break;  //going outside the while loop
      }

      while(sample() > light_1 )
        sleep(1);  //waiting the end of the irst flash.

      }
      if (fail)
        continue; // there was no 3 flashes whithin 4 seconds, so we restart from the beginning of the for loop 
      else
        do function // do the function you want...


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm getting this wrong, but wouldn't the following code suffice?

```
// Data type and initial value for these two vars must be apt for this scenario.
int last_light = 0;
int current_light = 0;

for(uint8_t crescent_flashes = 0; TRUE; last_light = current_light){
  current_light = sample();

  if(current_light <= last_light){
    crescent_flashes = 0;
    continue;
  }

  crescent_flashes++;

  if(crescent_flashes == 3){
    do_smart_stuff();
    crescent_flashes = 0;
  }else{
    sleep(1second);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the part that's not explicit?

Comment: The for loop, can you please explain the conditions ?

Comment: Can't get this formatted, sorry. _uint8_t crescent_flashes = 0;_ // Simple value initialization

_TRUE;_ // Run loop forever

_last_light = current_light_ // At the end of each loop, current_light becomes last_light

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just 10x bigger, than you expect. If you wanna solve it yourself, fisrt of all, leave the keyboard alone, and try to **design** the stuff.

Basically, you only one information about a lamp: on or off. That's not enough for such complex operations, like checking flash count in a specified time interval. You have to create *derivatives*.

First of all, you have to set up some kind of counter or timestamp, which is used to calculate time intervals, like elapsed time, distance between two events and so on. It can be a timestamp (provided by the operating system or the language you are using), or if your program is an endless loop, you can put a sleep() and a counter++ into it, and use that for measuring time (OK, it's less accurate because it does not counts with the time during the program runs, but it does not matter in this time precision).

Your derivatived varialbes will be something like:

- light change; parameters: way (up/down), timestamp
- flash: a series of events, where the first is up, the second is down, parameters: begin, end and (calculated from these:) duration.

You will have to detect and store these events, minimum the last N ones, where N is the biggest number appears on your conditions (e.g. if you wanna detect 3 times flash, you have to store last 3 flashes at least). Maybe, a ringbuffer is the best solution.

When you have a series of detected events, you have to check your condition on each change, e.g. check wheter the lamp is flashed in the last X secs.

Use paper, draw a timeline, name and draw your terms (like event), run your detection algorhythms "on paper".

Again: the problem you are fighting with is **even bigger** than you tought it first. But if you split the problem to smaller problem layers (layer 1: atomic changes -> events; layer 2: events -> queue of events; layer 3: event series analyzing), they are small problems, which is easy to solve.

First, it will be hard to thinking in that multi-layer constrution, and it's hard to not to mix the layers, but if you have proper low-level layers, you can do more complex magic in the upper levels, or build even more complex layers, like detecting morse signals.

Comment: Hope, you'll be able to write your own code. It is a really good practice. Maybe, you will return amd return to some issues: why do I need to store last N events instead of last 1? How should I avoid non-real things, say, when two "lamp on" comes without no "lamp off" event between them? Anyway, the final program will look like a simple thing, and you'll find it simple, too. (Notice: I've written a complete home aut. system w/ my friend, I've met similar problems.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you want to do is this: detect that the light has flashed 3 times within the last 4 seconds. By 'flash' I take it that you mean that the light was off and then it went on. (It could of course be that by 'flash' you mean that the light must go on and then off, and that would require a more complicated solution, but since you have not given us a definition of what you mean by flash, I will go with the easier version.)

First of all, checking whether your light reading now is greater than or lesser than your light reading at some point in the past will not tell you whether the light went on or off. You need to establish a low threshold value below which you will consider the light to be off, and a high threshold value above which you will consider the light to be on. When the reading varies below the low threshold, you ignore it. When the reading varies between the two thresholds, you also ignore it. And when the reading varies above the high threshold, you guessed it, again, you ignore it. You only care about the following two cases:

1. The lamp was off, and the previous reading was below the high threshold, and the new reading is above the high threshold; this means that the lamp is now on.
2. The lamp was on, and the previous reading was above the low threshold, and the new reading is below the low threshold; this means that the lamp is now off.

If you do not do that, then you will get lots of false triggers, as the reading of your LDR will vary as someone walks by wearing a highly reflective white lab coat, or simply just due to random noise.

And since we have taken a flash to mean a transition from 'off' to 'on', you actually only have to care about the first case above. (Otherwise, you need to take both cases into account.)

So, what you need to do is have an array with three entries in which you store the time at which each one of the last three flashes occurred. Every time a new flash occurs you discard the time value in the first element of the array, you shift the next two down, and you store the new time value in the last element of the array. Each time you do that, you check to see whether the difference between the first and the last entry is less than or equal to 4 seconds.

Note: under no circumstances should you ever use a sleep or wait or delay function, because while your program is sleeping, the light could flash, and you would miss it.

Comment: Thanks for the informative reply, my only problem is that I cant get a proper reading from the ADC, all I get is noise. This prevents me from providing a condition that responds to a certain threshold, thus I have to depend on the condition that the sampled light NOW is greater than the sampled light BEFORE.

Comment: If *all* you get is noise, then there is no point in working on this project, because it will never work.  If you are getting *some* noise, or even *a lot* of noise, then that's **precisely** why you should use the thresholds that I suggested instead of your overly simplistic approach.

Comment: I then have to find a way to filter the results.  Maybe im reading off the wrong pin.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to first establish that you have good input from the hardware before you can hope to get anything to work in software.

Answer (score 0):

I think your description could mean you never break (if your conditions don't happen within 3 seconds). Is that what you intend? I have a feeling you want to break once you sampled 4 times, and samples 2-4 were higher than sample 1; and this happened within 3 seconds.

For that interpretation of your question, you could create the counter as a structure with the following fields:

s1, s2, s3, s4
count
t1, t2, t3, t4

Initialize all to 0. At arrival of first sample, store value in s1 and its jiffies in t1.

Iteration: if new sample <= s1, store it in s1/t1. If not, store it in s2, its jiffies in t2, increase count by 1, and  t_elapsed by (jiffies - t1). As long as new samples are > s1 and t_elapsed <= 3 secs, handle similarly and store in next free sx and tx element. If you reach a count of 3 with t_elapsed <= 3 secs, break.

If any new sample <= s1 or t_elapsed > 3 secs, rotate down: s2 and t2 to s1 and t1,  s3/t3 into s2/t2, and s4/t4 into s3/t3. If s1 >= s2, rotate down again. Once (if) s1

This obviously will not be totally precise, for time elapsed in algorithm. You also face a risk of process pre-emption, interrupts and such, and might want to think If that is acceptable, or if you want to protect your structure with a mutex or such.

Comment: It should read: Once (if) s1 < s2, or if only s1/t1 left, null top not used entries. If s1<s2, set count to 1 and t_elapsed to (t2-t1). If s3 not null, update again. Wait for more signals.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I want to try avoid using a time condition because I realized its quite complex in code (im not very efficient at programming). So I thought of having an array that stores values and break the loop when the array is full. I will add a delay of 1 second from my own function to store each value in the array as 1 (sample) per second. Can I break the loop if the array becomes full ?